# JavaScript throws null outputs from getAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this JavaScript snipe to extract content from the page:

```
const res = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gs-webResult gs-result')).reduce(function(res, parent, index) {
  const name = parent.querySelector('.gs-title').textContent;
  const age = parent.querySelector('.gs-snippet').textContent;
  const url = parent.querySelector('.title').getAttribute('href');
  const img = parent.querySelector('.gs-image').getAttribute('src');
  res[name] = { name, age, url, img };

  return res;

}, {});

console.log(res)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gs-webResult gs-result">
    <div class="gsc-thumbnail-inside">
        <div class="gs-title"><a class="gs-title" href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj_uKH9l5HcAhVFXn0KHS0dDAYQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=017093085003369662669:vlgrcqgvtxk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2AJoa0Ih-fNpOLvlOxmdNS" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj_uKH9l5HcAhVFXn0KHS0dDAYQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=017093085003369662669:vlgrcqgvtxk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2AJoa0Ih-fNpOLvlOxmdNS" data-ctorig="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts">AMIDEAST <b>Yemen</b> - Posts | Facebook</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gsc-url-top">
        <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-short" dir="ltr">en-gb.facebook.com</div>
        <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-long" dir="ltr" style="word-break:break-all;">https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEAST<b>Yemen</b>/<b>posts</b></div>
    </div>
    <table class="gsc-table-result">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail" style="">
                    <div class="gs-image-box gs-web-image-box gs-web-image-box-portrait">
                        <a class="gs-image" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts" target="_blank" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj_uKH9l5HcAhVFXn0KHS0dDAYQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=017093085003369662669:vlgrcqgvtxk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2AJoa0Ih-fNpOLvlOxmdNS" data-ctorig="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts"><img class="gs-image" onload="if (this.parentNode &amp;&amp; this.parentNode.parentNode &amp;&amp; this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode) { this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = ''; this.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'gs-image-box gs-web-image-box gs-web-image-box-portrait'; } " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrsTbHMW2YtzbtH4kGtfVETKB2cVeEXB74D4yVwDKCP2mI53yzQ4Vc_FFB"></a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="gsc-table-cell-snippet-close">
                    <div class="gs-title gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail-left"><a class="gs-title" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj_uKH9l5HcAhVFXn0KHS0dDAYQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=017093085003369662669:vlgrcqgvtxk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2AJoa0Ih-fNpOLvlOxmdNS" data-ctorig="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts">AMIDEAST <b>Yemen</b> - Posts | Facebook</a></div>
                    <div><span></span></div>
                    <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-snippet" dir="ltr">“AMIDEAST is offering <b>Yemeni</b> youth a unique opportunity by working in a professional environment and equips them with the necessary skills and tools to begin&nbsp;...
                    </div>
                    <div class="gsc-url-bottom">
                        <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-short" dir="ltr">en-gb.facebook.com</div>
                        <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-long" dir="ltr" style="word-break:break-all;">https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEAST<b>Yemen</b>/<b>posts</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gs-richsnippet-box" style="display: block;"><span class="gsc-richsnippet-showsnippet-label" tabindex="0">Structured data</span></div>
                    <div class="gs-per-result-labels" url="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts"><span>Labeled</span><a class="gs-label" data-refinementlabel="facebook" label-with-op="more:facebook" dir="ltr" tabindex="0">Facebook</a><span></span></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The code works well when getting .gs-title and gs-snippet
But when I try to get the image source using `.getAttribute` I get `null` output values

Any idea?

Comment: Please try debugging this. What are `parent.querySelector('.title')` and `parent.querySelector('.image')`? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: You don't have to use `.getAttribute()` to get the "href" of an `<a>` element or the "src" of an `<img>`. You can get them directly as properties of the DOM nodes.

Comment: The HTML for the img looks like this `<a class="image" href="xx.com" target="_blank" src="xxx.png">
<img class="image" src="xxx.png">
</a>` the HTML for the title look like this : `<a class="title" href="xxx.com target="_blank">AMIDEAST</a>`

Comment: @Pointy Could you kindly make an answer?

Comment: @Gad So this means that `parent.querySelector('.image')` is your `<a>` element which doesn’t have a `src`. Try `img.image` as a selector instead. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `<a class="title" href="xxx.com target="_blank">AMIDEAST</a>` is invalid HTML. Where’s the `parent`? This is not enough context.

Comment: @Xufox I have updated the question with the entire examples, kindly take a look.

Comment: @Gad I don’t see any `.Result` and `.title` elements in the HTML. As for `.gs-image` not having a `src`, I’ve already explained that in my second comment. Perhaps the [`querySelector` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will further help you.

Comment: To rephrase @Xufox’s comment, if it helps: the first `.gs-image` in the document is an `<a>`. You want the second one, which is an `<img>`. You can get it by making the selector more specific.

Comment: I tried using it in this way to make it specific `const img = parent.querySelector('img.gs-image').getAttribute("src");` but it still didn't work.

Any idea

Comment: I also tried this `const img = parent.querySelector('img.gs-image').src;` but it still didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @Gad: Your base selector `document.querySelectorAll('.gs-webResult gs-result')` is wrong since `gs-result` is a class aswell. Try `document.querySelectorAll('.gs-webResult.gs-result')`. Try `document.querySelector('img.gs-image').src` and you will see it working - hence your selectors are wrong.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have provided me a full code.

And below is JS code.

```
const defaultURL = "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/904380/screenshots/2233565/attachments/415915/revised-google-logo.png";
const res = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gs-webResult')).reduce(function(res, parent, index) {
    const name = parent.querySelector('.gs-title').textContent;
    const age = parent.querySelector('.gs-snippet').textContent;
    const url = parent.querySelector('a.gs-title').getAttribute('href');
    const img = parent.querySelector('a.gs-image .gs-image')? parent.querySelector('a.gs-image .gs-image').getAttribute('src') : defaultURL;

    // console.log(img);

    res[name] = { name, age, url, img };

    return res;

}, {});

console.log(res);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(".image")` is unlikely to work.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: There is always a workaround. He posted this question after lots of debugging of course. I have given him the workaround to solve the issue.

Comment: @HardikShah This is not a workaround. The code is mostly equivalent to the OP’s code. There is not enough information to provide a working solution. The OP provided part of the HTML after your answer, and your code will still not work with the OP’s code.

Comment: @Ry-♦  I have updated the question with the entire examples, kindly take a look.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` does not use a selector prefix. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: @Gad, Please have a look of the modified answer. May this help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, I don't have control over the code as it's being fetched from remote url, it would be great if you can find solution for this condition.

Comment: For the href in this format `const url = parent.querySelector('a.gs-title').href;`
for for the image it's still happening.

Comment: @Gad, can you please try like this `const url = parent.querySelector('.gs-title .gs-title').getAttribute('href');
                        const img = parent.querySelector('.gs-image .gs-image').getAttribute('src');`

Comment: it worked for the href in this format `const url = parent.querySelector('a.gs-title').href;` but for the image it didn't.

Comment: @Gad, take a look as I have updated the answer. It's working perfectly in my case.

Comment: Your code works if the `gs-webResult gs-result` is one in the page but there is multiple then it won't work

Comment: in this example I've included the entire source code.

Comment: @Gad, I have changed the code as per your entire HTML code is given by codepen. You will have an error because 4th number element does not have the image. So, you need to take care of the `null` value where images are not available. Take a look here `https://jsfiddle.net/HardikShah/vye4m0Lo/3/`

Comment: @Gad, Working like a charm as per your codepen code !!! Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: It worked, many thanks for your great effort, I made an up vote and I hope people will give you up vote for your efficiency .

Comment: @Gad, Any time. You got the solution is worth for me. :)

Comment: @HardikShah I appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

There are three major issues:

1. The base selector '.gs-webResult gs-result' is wrong - brings no results
2. There is not element with the class 'title' - null reference error
3. 'gs-image' is not necessarily an image - could be `div`, `a`, `img`

```js
window.onload = function(){
 //REM: Fix the selector '.gs-webResult gs-result' to '.gs-webResult.gs-result'
 const res = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gs-webResult.gs-result')).reduce(function(res, parent, index) {
  const name = parent.querySelector('.gs-title') ? parent.querySelector('.gs-title').textContent : '';
  const age = parent.querySelector('.gs-snippet') ? parent.querySelector('.gs-snippet').textContent : '';

  //REM: There is not classname 'title' in use
  const url = parent.querySelector('.title') ? parent.querySelector('.title').getAttribute('href') : ''; 

  //REM: Add 'img.' to the selector
  const img = parent.querySelector('img.gs-image') ? parent.querySelector('img.gs-image').getAttribute('src') : '';

  //REM: Be aware that this implied key assignment does not work on older browsers
  res[name] = { name, age, url, img };

  return res
 }, {});

 console.log(res)
}
```

```html
<div class="gs-webResult gs-result">
    <div class="gsc-thumbnail-inside">
        <div class="gs-title"><a class="gs-title" href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj_uKH9l5HcAhVFXn0KHS0dDAYQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=017093085003369662669:vlgrcqgvtxk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2AJoa0Ih-fNpOLvlOxmdNS" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj_uKH9l5HcAhVFXn0KHS0dDAYQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=017093085003369662669:vlgrcqgvtxk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2AJoa0Ih-fNpOLvlOxmdNS" data-ctorig="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts">AMIDEAST <b>Yemen</b> - Posts | Facebook</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gsc-url-top">
        <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-short" dir="ltr">en-gb.facebook.com</div>
        <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-long" dir="ltr" style="word-break:break-all;">https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEAST<b>Yemen</b>/<b>posts</b></div>
    </div>
    <table class="gsc-table-result">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail" style="">
                    <div class="gs-image-box gs-web-image-box gs-web-image-box-portrait">
                        <a class="gs-image" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts" target="_blank" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj_uKH9l5HcAhVFXn0KHS0dDAYQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=017093085003369662669:vlgrcqgvtxk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2AJoa0Ih-fNpOLvlOxmdNS" data-ctorig="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts"><img class="gs-image" onload="if (this.parentNode &amp;&amp; this.parentNode.parentNode &amp;&amp; this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode) { this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = ''; this.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'gs-image-box gs-web-image-box gs-web-image-box-portrait'; } " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrsTbHMW2YtzbtH4kGtfVETKB2cVeEXB74D4yVwDKCP2mI53yzQ4Vc_FFB"></a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="gsc-table-cell-snippet-close">
                    <div class="gs-title gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail-left"><a class="gs-title" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-cturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwj_uKH9l5HcAhVFXn0KHS0dDAYQFggEMAA&amp;client=internal-uds-cse&amp;cx=017093085003369662669:vlgrcqgvtxk&amp;usg=AOvVaw2AJoa0Ih-fNpOLvlOxmdNS" data-ctorig="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts">AMIDEAST <b>Yemen</b> - Posts | Facebook</a></div>
                    <div><span></span></div>
                    <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-snippet" dir="ltr">“AMIDEAST is offering <b>Yemeni</b> youth a unique opportunity by working in a professional environment and equips them with the necessary skills and tools to begin&nbsp;...
                    </div>
                    <div class="gsc-url-bottom">
                        <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-short" dir="ltr">en-gb.facebook.com</div>
                        <div class="gs-bidi-start-align gs-visibleUrl gs-visibleUrl-long" dir="ltr" style="word-break:break-all;">https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEAST<b>Yemen</b>/<b>posts</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gs-richsnippet-box" style="display: block;"><span class="gsc-richsnippet-showsnippet-label" tabindex="0">Structured data</span></div>
                    <div class="gs-per-result-labels" url="https://en-gb.facebook.com/AMIDEASTYemen/posts"><span>Labeled</span><a class="gs-label" data-refinementlabel="facebook" label-with-op="more:facebook" dir="ltr" tabindex="0">Facebook</a><span></span></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```